# Does there exist a metric space and meanwhile a group X such that its multiplication operation is continuous but inverse operation is discontinuous?

Tags: general-topology

The title is the question.

Does there exist a metric space and meanwhile a group X such that its multiplication operation is continuous but inverse operation is discontinuous?
  I have questioned this problem but one may cannot see this. So I let it be alone. I really find it difficult for me. And I think maybe the (counter-)example is not so complex. Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition and with the "lower limit topology" generated by the half-open intervals $[x,y)_r := [x,y) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x<y$.

Here, addition is continuous roughly because, if $a+b \in [x,x+y)$, then so is $a+b + \epsilon$ when $\epsilon$ is a small enough positive number.

Inversion is not continuous. The negative of $[0,1)_r$ is not open.

The topology is metrizeable because it is 2nd countable and regular. In fact, the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to the standard topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ (under a non-identity homeomorphism,  of course) by a theorem of Sierpinski! See [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm).

**Edit:** Fixed the link, which actually went to the wrong page.

Comment: The idea for this example came from another post, which unfortunately had a small glitch in it. It seems the author has now deleted this post.

Comment: You are so nice and so clever. I know that topological completeness is a topological property. However metric completeness is not a topological property. In fact, this rational number lower limit topogy is really  metrizeable because it is 2nd countable, kolmogorov and regular?

Comment: That's correct although, for me, *regular* includes *Hausdorff* so the Kolmogorov assumption is not neccessary. I'm not sure why you mention completeness here. As you may know, the standard topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be induced by any complete metric. This is a consequence of the Baire category theorem.